# docker.io - Docker linking between application & database containers

Tags: mysql, scala, docker

I am trying to use my Scala-Akka application with my MySQL database on two separate Docker containers. I found out that Docker allows developers to link their application to their databases with the flag named --link. In my Dockerfiles in which I've used to create my images, I have add in EXPOSE 3306 8080 to it.

And this is how I run the containers:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql centos6mysql
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name scalaapp --link mysql:db centos6scala
```

After running the containers, I used docker ps and I am able to see the active containers. However, It seems like the application container is not using the database from the MySQL container. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: you might want to be more explicit about what you mean by >It seems like the application container is not using the database from the MySQL container.

Comment: I created a restcore script which starts up my scala-akka app. My application container will basically start up the script when I run it.

Comment: My script will allow me to bound a port which is 8080 to the container. After running both of the app and db containers, I go on to the browser and enter in http://<host ip address>:8080/v1/<some organization>/1. Expectation: It will return me the DB record with ID 1. Reality: It just says internal server error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linking in Docker allows network connections to be made between containers. Docker will define environmental variables to your linked containers for the URL, IP, port, and protocol. The names of these will be based on the name of your container. For instance:

```
DB_NAME=/web2/db
DB_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.5:5432
DB_PORT_5432_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.5:5432
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PROTO=tcp
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.5
```

You can use these environmental variables to set up your Akka app container to connect to your DB container. However, you must manually configure the app container to do so. Docker will not make the connection for you automatically.

So, somewhere in your app, you will need to pass these values to your startup script, something that might look like:

```
./restcore --Ddb.default.db="jdbc:mysql//${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}:${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT"
```

Comment: I've edited it accordingly with ${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}:${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT}/mydb on my MySQL connector jar file in which was used in the restcore script file. I run the app container with environment variables -e "DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=<MySQL container IP>" -e "DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306". I have no idea why the Docker link does not set my environment variables automatically. Afterwards, I check out the outcome on my browser with port 8080 and it still doesn't show the records from the database that I want...

Comment: What I found out is that even after using the link between my app and db containers, it does not even set my environment variables. I have already expose 3306 on my MySQL Dockerfile though...

Comment: I've solved the problem. It worked now and DB records can be seen. What I did is that I exec into my app container and check the environment using env. It showed the MySQL environment variables! For some reason, inspecting the container doesn't list the variables but going into the container and checking from it works. Thanks for your help! :)