# docker: connect to database container via dockerhost

Tags: docker

I am trying to connect from an application container to a database container in two situations, one succeeds, one doesn't.

There are two containers on my dockerhost:

1. mysql container with port 3306 connected to 3356 on dockerhost
2. application container

At work, dockerhost has IP-address 10.0.2.15, at home, dockerhost has IP-address 192.168.8.11 (hostname -I).
In both situations, I want to connect to the database container from the app container with host 10.0.2.15/192.168.8.11 and port 3356.

When I do this at work (Windows network, Vagrant/Virtualbox dockerhost), this is no problem. I can 'telnet 10.0.2.15 3356' from the app container and connect to the db container.
When I do this at home (Ubuntu), it is impossible to connect. The only way is to use the docker ip address of the db container (172.17.0.2) with port 3306. However, I can ping 192.168.8.11.

The scripts to start the containers are identical; I do not use --add-host, so the dockerhost IP-address is not in /etc/hosts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the documentation on linking containers: http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Comment: And the most recent version of Docker introduces new networking capabilities: http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

Comment: I did read the documentation. The question is, why does it work in one situation and not in another, identical. Using Docker 1.9 in both cases.

Comment: The point is you don't have to use IP addresses and port numbers at all. In fact you shouldn't because as you've discovered they can be different on different host machines. There are lots and lots of examples, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061225/docker-io-docker-linking-between-application-database-containers

Comment: Forget it. If you don't want to read the question, don't try to answer it.

Comment: That's not a very nice way of responding to someone who's trying to help. You could at least upvote the answer from @MarkO'Connor, even if you don't think it solved your problem. Even better would be to retract your rather grumpy comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, use docker to run 3 database instances

```
docker run --name mysqldb1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme -d mysql
docker run --name mysqldb2 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme -d mysql
docker run --name mysqldb3 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme -d mysql
```

Each one will have a different IP address on my host machine:

```
$ for i in mysqldb1 mysqldb2 mysqldb3
> do   
> docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $i
> done
172.17.0.2
172.17.0.3
172.17.0.4
```

Repeat this on your machine and you'll very likely have different IP addresses.

So how is this problem fixed.

The older approach (deprecated in docker 1.9) is to use links. The following commands will shows how environment variables are set within your linked application container (the one using the database)

```
$ docker run -it --rm --link mysqldb1:mysql mysql env 
..
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.2

$ docker run -it --rm --link mysqldb2:mysql mysql env 
..
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3

$ docker run -it --rm --link mysqldb3:mysql mysql env 
..
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.4
```

And the following demonstrates how links are also created:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --link mysqldb1:mysql mysql grep mysql /etc/hosts
172.17.0.2  mysql 2a12644351a0 mysqldb1

$ docker run -it --rm --link mysqldb2:mysql mysql grep mysql /etc/hosts
172.17.0.3  mysql 89140cbf68c7 mysqldb2

$ docker run -it --rm --link mysqldb3:mysql mysql grep mysql /etc/hosts
172.17.0.4  mysql 27535e8848ef mysqldb3
```

So you can just refer to the other container using the "mysql" hostname or the "MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" environment variable.

---

In Docker 1.9 there is a more powerful networking feature that enables containers to be linked across hosts.

http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

Comment: +1 for just this bit of magic alone: `docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}` :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use my container acting as a NAT gateway to dockerhost without any manually setup https://github.com/qoomon/docker-host