# Docker: Granting access to linked mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker

So I have a mysql-client container and a mysql-database container, just for testing purposes. I have linked the 2 containers using docker run --link.

Now I want to create a user in the database and grant it select, create, update, etc. access, so that it can connect to the database and perform queries, etc.

So, the /etc/hosts file on the client container now has an entry for the server, which is great, but my question now is:

Since the IP addresses of the containers can change when I re-run the containers, how do I grant permissions to a user to access the server from the client, as the client will be seen as being remote?

Example in mysql client:

```
mysql> grant select, update on db.* to 'test'@'???????' identified by 'testpw'
```

Surely I cannot use 'localhost' instead of the '???????' above, but I also cannot hard code the IP address of the client container, as that can change next time I run it?

I think I am miss understanding how linked dockers work in this scenario :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the wildcard `%` to allow any remote ip:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON *.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: Thanks for that. And I guess this is secure enough, because only clients that are "linked" to the DB-server container will be able to connect in any case, right?

Comment: You're right until you don't publish the mysql port with the host. This is the default configuration of official mysql image https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/4e022c06314ff6047dabc4abee2f222ae9ce564d/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L60

Comment: To  complete, see this post on container linking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061225/docker-io-docker-linking-between-application-database-containers

Comment: Great! Thanks a million for that :)